# Partial content is not visible in the side bar

Tags: bug, design, display

There is some display issue in the side bar in some browsers.

The **see an example newsletter** content is partially not visible in the side bar.

[image: Sidebar content in Firefox]

Firefox Version: 44.0b9

It's very similar in Chrome 47 on Windows:

[image: Sidebar in Chrome]

And in IE11 on Windows:

[image: Sidebar in IE]

The last two images are from a machine with Helvetica installed, but the ad is still truncated.

Comment: I do not have this problem in unbuntu, firefox 43.0.4

Comment: It's not just Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the alignment issue is fixed in Firebox, Chrome and IE 11.

The latest side bar screenshot is:

[image: Latest side bar]